# How to Sort arraylist of object containing Date in Reverse Order

Tags: java, android, sorting

I was able to sort in ascending order but can't figure out in descending order.Here is the code that I have used.

```
public class RssItemComparator implements Comparator<RssItem> {
    DateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm");
    Date date1, date2;

    @Override
    public int compare(RssItem rssItem1, RssItem rssItem2) {
        try {
            date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(rssItem1.getPubDate());
            date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(rssItem2.getPubDate());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date2.compareTo(date1);

    }
}
```

this created sort in an unusual manner.Eg:

1. Fri,24 Nov 2017 05:07
2. Fri,24 Nov 2017 04:34
3. Fri,24 Nov 2017 02:11
4. Thu,23 Nov 2017 13:55

Answer (score 0):

try create an instance of movie when the activity is showing and delete it when you change to a new activity. that should solve the ran out of memory problem.

Activity Life Cycle - https://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png

before an activity is going to show it runs onResume() - this could be where you create and prepare the movie to show,

and then before it disappear because a new activty come on top of it or user close an app, it runs onPause() - this could be where you delete movie to avoid running out of memory problem

```
// import declarations ommited

public class DetailActivity extends Activity {

 Movie aMovie;
 // other variables ommited

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // other logics ommited
 }

 // this will run everytime an instance of DetailActivity is on a screen
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
    // create and instance of aMovie and show it
    // this will ensure the same movie of this instance of DetailActivity will show everytime when it's showing on screen
 }

 // this will run everytime an instance of DetailActivity is closed or, another instance of an activity is pushed on top of it
 @Override
 public void onPause() {
    // remove, delete or free resource of an instance of aMovie
    // so this will help about not running out of memory since we 
 }

 // other methods ommited
}
```

Comment: What about when the user presses back button?i need to show the movie list that was clicked before

Comment: if back button is pressed, a previous activity could remember what movie to show and create an instance of it

Comment: the new activity i am opening is the same moviedetail activity.How can i delete that movie detail activity?sorry i am beginner in android programming and if i delete the movie to avoid the running out of memory problem then that means when i click the back button the last movie which was shown is not remembered?

Comment: how do you show and keep reference of a movie in your app?

Comment: sorry i didnt get you what you mean..but there is no database to save the reference

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant, in code how do you show movie in application, and how is your movie object/instance

Comment: from intent i called that movie detail activity in on click listener

Comment: In moviedetail activity there is a section where it shows the similar movies and when we click movie detail item(movie) from intent  movie detail is called again